# Is there some way to echo from terminal into new vim buffer

Tags: options, startup

Let's say I do a simple shell command like `ls`. Is there some way to directly pipe the output into a new vim buffer, so that I could edit it in place or just have a look at it.

Basically like `less` + the ability to edit it and directly save it in some place on the system?

Comment: [How do I redirect command output to vim in bash?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/510890/how-do-i-redirect-command-output-to-vim-in-bash)

Answer (score 5):

You can do this from directly inside of vim with the `:read` command, which is abbreviated to `:r` The 'read' command is intended to allow you to read a file, e.g.

```
:r foo.txt
```

Will insert the contents of `foo.txt` after your current cursor position.

From `:help :r`

```
                            *:r* *:re* *:read*
:r[ead] [++opt] [name]
            Insert the file [name] (default: current file) below
            the cursor.
            See |++opt| for the possible values of [++opt].
```

However, you can read a command that outputs to STOUT just as if it was a file. To call the external command, just prepend an exclamation mark. This gives us:

```
:r !ls
```

You can also do this from the terminal before you start vim by using pipes. For example

```
ls | vim
```

However, you must explicitly tell vim to read from STDIN, which can by starting vim with a `-` at the end.

```
ls | vim -
```

From :help --`

```
                            *--*
-       This argument can mean two things, depending on whether Ex
        mode is to be used.

        Starting in Normal mode: >
            vim -
            ex -v -
        Start editing a new buffer, which is filled with text
        that is read from stdin.  The commands that would normally be
        read from stdin will now be read from stderr.  Example: >
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just get the input from a terminal command, then just do the following

```
ls | vim -
```

Same for any other command output you want to pipe to Vim.
If you want to read the output you can use `read` or `r` as already mentioned. You can also use the dot (`.`) to do the same. 
So doing this,

```
: . !ls
```

will give the same result as using `read`. 
Similarly for inserting date,

```
: . !date
```